# How to make a struct stored in two different memory pages in linux kernel?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, struct, linux-kernel

I'm not good at English, I will try my best to make the problem clear.

Supposing I have a struct which is:

```
struct A {
   /* the first half */
   int a;
   int b;
   /* the second half */
   int c;
   int d;
} ;
```

We know that the members of A will be stored continuously in memory. However, I want to make the first half and the second half of A stored in two different memory pages, which means the struct is partitioned in memory. How can I achieve it?
Suppose that struct A is a structure in linux kernel, So I'm programming in kernel space. And the kernel version is 3.10.

**Update**:To make my goal clear, I draw following picture, which is the memory layout I want, this can avoid the waste of memory space:
[image]

Comment: For all reasonable purposes, you can't this in C.

Comment: How about the align macro or the __attribute__((align())? Is this useful?@DavidHoelzer

Comment: And why would you want to do this ??

Comment: For some security purposes.@MichaelWalz

Comment: Pad it up to 2x page size & align it to page size.

Comment: I don't understand well, could you please show some code and give as an answer?@R..

Comment: You'll have to do a fair bit of hacking to manage that. You'll require a custom allocator the relies on working in kernel space, to ensure it only returns chunks at the end of a memory page, if any are available.

Comment: I do wonder why the hell you'd want to do that, though. C programs usually strive to minimize page misses.

Comment: Please see the update.@StoryTeller

Comment: Why don't you just let the OS and it's allocator worry about wasting memory space. It will do a far better job than you or me, and your program will not suffer in performance. If your struct causes two page misses every time you need to fetch cold memory, you will not be happy.

Comment: You say, "For some security purposes," but I suspect you are spending an enormous amount of effort and time for virtually no benefit. After all, if both pages are accessible from the same process (which they will be since you are allocating the memory from a single process), there's really nothing to be gained in terms of "security."

Comment: In this way, I can make some data of  struct A gathered in a read-only page to protect them.@DavidHoelzer

Comment: Refactor the "read-only" parts into a separate struct (place it in whatever page you want), and store a pointer to it in the original struct. Than you won't have to resort to hacking.

Comment: The picture you provide **contradicts continious nature** of structure object: Only single structure object may cross *page1*-*page2* boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to make struct memory non-contiguous use pointers and do kmalloc.

```
struct first_half  {
 int a;
 int b;
};

struct second_half {
int c;
int d;
};    


 struct A {
    /* the first half */
    struct first_half *fh;
    /* the second half */
    struct second_half *sh;
 } ;

 fh = (struct first_half *) kmalloc();
 sh = (struct second_half *) kmalloc();
```

Comment: Note that the casts are unnecessary here, `void*` converts implicitly to any pointer in C.

Comment: Note that A is a kernel structure, if it is changed in this way, many kernel codes which refer to A have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding padding between members of the structure and allocating it on a page boundary, e.g.:

```
struct A {
    int a, b;
    char padding[PAGE_SIZE - 2 * sizeof(int)];
    int c, d;
};
```

However, that only handles pages of one size (e.g. 4KB), whereas there are huge pages of different sizes (2MB and 1GB on x86_64).

Alternatively, if padding is undesirable, allocate the memory for the structure in such a way, so that the object straddles a page boundary.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! Is there a way that  I can use the memory space of padding to store another struct A  rather than just waste it?

Comment: @hexiecs You can put anything you please in the padding. Understanding C and structure memory layout is a prerequisite for any kind of software security though.

Comment: Hi, please see the update, which is the memory layout I want.

Comment: @hexiecs That is basically two arrays of different `struct`s on two different pages. Break your `struct` in two and use the same index to access associated elements (halfs) from different arrays.

Comment: Hi, just  as I have mentioned in other comments, breaking the struct is not  so good because other codes related to struct A have to be changed in linux kernel.